# How to use regex in Perl to see if a variable has only specific characters?

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to use regex in Perl to see if a scalar variable has any characters other than the ones I'm looking for.  The placement or order of the characters don't matter.

For example if want to filter out other than the characters C and F:

Matching to ABCADF would equal true (it has other than my filter characters)

Matching FFC would equal false.

Matching CCCC would also equal false.

Thanks

Comment: Just search for `/[^CF]/`

Comment: @ysth Thank you.  Follow up if I may:   `if($notes =~ /[^CF]/)` works.  But how do I do the "not" match?  Have tried =! and that doesn't work.  For now just doing what I need in the `else` section.  Just want to be more precise.  Thanks again.

Comment: The not match operator is `!~`

Comment: Please answer in answers, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following returns true if the string contains a character that is neither `C` nor `F`:

```
$str =~ /[^CF]/
```

---

In the comments, you mentioned you actually want the opposite. You could negate the above as follows:

```
!( $str =~ /[^CF]/ )
$str !~ /[^CF]/
```

If you'd rather avoid the double-negative, you could check if the string consists entirely of `C` and `F` characters.

```
$str =~ /^[CF]*\z/
```

Comment: While my question has been answered what does the *\z do?  It works without that part, so not sure that that means?

Comment: `*` means "0 or more of the previous atom". `\z` matches the end of string (just like `^` matches the start of string)

Comment: And it most definitely does not work without that part. `/^[CF]/` merely checks if the string starts with one of `C` or `F`.

Comment: And it most definitely does not work without that part. `/^[CF]/` merely checks if the string starts with one of `C` or `F`.

Comment: maybe you misread the question, because with the *\z it doesn't work

Comment: That is correct. As my answer states, it does the opposite of what you asked in the question, as you asked in a comment.

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused.  I just want to regex formula to sort out which scalars have ONLY the characters C and F and no other notes.  Where it starts, if there are duplicates, etc, doesn't matter.  The moment a 'D' or 'F' shows up, that scalar gets flagged.

Comment: That is why you asked in your question and that is answered by the first half of my answer. Use `$str =~ /[^CF]/`.

Comment: What I am using is `if($notes->[$x] !~ /[^CDE]/)` and if I fall into that bracket I splice that element.   When I tried it as `if($notes->[$x] !~ /[^CDE]*\z/)` it didn't work properly.

Comment: That's cause that's not what I wrote. You removed the `^` and negated the character class

Comment: You're correct my apologies..  Just realized that you had the bracket outside. So if I do `if($notes->[$x] !~ /^[CDE]*\z/)`it actually appears to work the same as `if($notes->[$x] !~ /[^CDE]/)` and that's what I would love to understand

Comment: What you just said is incorrect. `$notes->[$x] !~ /^[CDE]*\z/` is not the same as `$notes->[$x] !~ /[^CDE]/`. In fact, it's exactly the opposite. `$notes->[$x] =~ /^[CDE]*\z/` would be the same as `$notes->[$x] !~ /[^CDE]/`

Comment: Yes, I meant to say =~, just a cut and past error.  So they both work, I just want to learn the difference between the two methods.

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: The two different ways to get the same result.  The one I use '$notes->[$x] !~ /[^CDE]/` I read it as "If any character in this scalar is not C D or E the if statement is true.

I don't know what `if($notes->[$x] =~ /^[CDE]*\z/)` translates to (even though it also returns true.

Comment: Re "*I read it as "If any character in this scalar is not C D or E the if statement is true.*", Not even close. `/[^CDE]/` means "contains a character that's not C/D/E", so `!/[^CDE]/` means "doesn't contain a character that's not C/D/E". If we flatten the double-negative, we get "contains only characters that are C/D/E".

Comment: `/^[CDE]*\z/` matches string that consists of zero or more C/D/E. In other words, it matches strings that contain only characters that are C/D/E.

Comment: Forget the IF part, and what returns true or false. `/[^CDE]/` works for me.    So does your contribution `/^[012]*\z/`  I just want to know how yours reads out as in english?  That's what I don't understand..

Comment: I just answered that

Comment: Yes, at the same time I was typing.

Comment: It was also in my Answer